# How to bind a GET request parameter safely to an Eloquent query

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-9

The problem is that I need to prevent SQL Injection.

I have the folowing route:

```
 Route::get('/data/{searchRequestId}', [RequestedDataController::class, 'GetData'])->name('data');
```

and this controller function:

```
    public function GetData(Request $request)
    {
        $requestedData = RequestedData::
        where('SearchRequestId', $request->searchRequestId)
        ->orderByDesc('SearchRequestId')
        ->cursorPaginate(8);

        if($requestedData->isEmpty()){
            return abort(404, "page not found");
        }

        return view('RequestedData', ['requestedData' => $requestedData]);
    }
```

Now when i call **/data/2'** (look at the quote), it will crash and the quote is litteraly in the query.

```
select top 9 * from [RequestedData] where [SearchRequestId] = 2' order by [SearchRequestId] desc
```

I don't understand why this is not escaped by laravel automaticaly, afterall I am not using raw queries.

The question is, what is the proper way to tackle this problem or pass the request parameter? I am using laravel 9 and sql server as database.

I tried using the query builder (DB::table('RequestedData') etc...), and i tried to pass the parameter with route().

```
$request->route('searchRequestId'))
```

Comment: The value is being passed in properly. Laravel's Eloquent uses prepared statements and parameter binding behind the scenes, but when it outputs the query for errors, it doesn't actually show all or even any quotes.

Comment: Typically syntax is `public function GetData(Request $request, $searchRequestId)`, as URL Parameters are passed to the associated Controller method, but you'll still get `2'` with either. But, single quotes are not valid in a URL, they should be escaped to `%27`. If you're on PHP 8, you can typehint this to trigger an error: `public function GetData(Request $request, int $searchRequestId)` will trigger an error: *"Argument #1 ($id) must be of type int, string given"*.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is your answer: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation

You can create a FormRequest or do it right in your controller

```
    public function GetData(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'searchRequestId' => 'integer'
        ]);
        $requestedData = RequestedData::
            where('SearchRequestId', $validated['searchRequestId'])
            ->orderByDesc('SearchRequestId')
            ->cursorPaginate(8);

        if($requestedData->isEmpty()){
            return abort(404, "page not found");
        }

        return view('RequestedData', ['requestedData' => $requestedData]);
    }
```

Edit: This won't work ^^.

@aynber's comment would be a better idea.

You could also type hint the controller function:

```
public function GetData(Request $request, int $searchRequestId)
```

Comment: Did you test this code? `$validated['searchRequestId']` triggers `Undefined array key "searchRequestId"`, since it is a URL Parameter, and not part of the `$request` object.

Comment: You _could_ use a Manual Validator, like `$validated = Validator::make(['searchRequestId' => $request->route('searchRequestId')], ['searchRequestId' => 'integer'])->validate();`, but using `$request->validate()` here does not work.

Comment: Using [Regular Expression Constraints on the route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) would be the more accepted way of validating the value.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Aynber, both of your solutions works perfectly! The difference is that the solution of Anyber will trigger a not found while the solution from Tim will just load the page. I think I will stick with the validation solution, it's a bit more user friendly that way. And thank you for the effort knapsack!